# Scaling a matrix (input matrix for neural network)

Tags: r, matrix, input, deep-learning, scale

I built a ML- model for a binary classification:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
    layer_batch_normalization(input_shape=input_shape) %>%
    layer_dense(units=128,activation='relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units=64, activation='relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units=32, activation='relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units=16, activation='relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units=8, activation='relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')

model %>% compile(
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer ='adam',
    metrics = list('accuracy'))

callbacks <-  callback_early_stopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=min_delta,patience=patience,verbose=1)

history <- model %>% fit(
    train[,chind],train[,gtind],
    batch_size = batch_size,
    epochs = epochs,
    callbacks = callbacks,
    validation_data =list(val[,chind],val[,gtind]),verbose = 1)

score <- model %>% evaluate(test[,chind], test[,gtind],)
```

I read that I need to standardize my inputs to a network that uses batch normalization and that [-1,1] scaling would be better than [0,1] scaling.

Could you help me to understand how this is done for an input matrix?
Do I scale column-wise?

Thank you!

This is what my input matrix looks like:

`dput(input[1:5,])`:

```
structure(c(284.783471152186, 281.587572842836, 273.633228540421, 
281.087069287896, 284.190191328526, 261.799371317029, 253.696096688509, 
250.878627896309, 255.539414659142, 246.11041598022, 270.351878404617, 
263.867305517197, 261.543015837669, 263.747672960162, 260.485854670405, 
283.338114544749, 280.535294637084, 272.456434816122, 280.535294637084, 
282.034363821149, 262.744224369526, 261.118198186159, 253.813287764788, 
262.856532484293, 263.625598922372, 284.981231093407, 282.962126508355, 
273.523361906409, 282.625202164054, 283.860591426492, 285.17166659236, 
282.798547297716, 273.706472963095, 282.525101453066, 283.411358967423, 
273.901791423559, 272.690816968679, 265.686208680272, 272.93496504426, 
272.690816968679, 250.810266435146, 243.419904187322, 238.993499577045, 
244.855494871736, 235.101779252291, 283.765373677015, 281.953794956207, 
272.712790295482, 281.685232073069, 282.781456932425, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), dim = c(5L, 11L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "gt")))
```